# How to write regex to get the value at nth position

Tags: regex

I want to fetch the data from the text. I have used the regular expression.
I have a content as

```
    2013
        Jan        Feb         March     April    May    June
       34,101.2  12,342.7    12,451.5
Value
```

**My regex**

```
2013.*?\s*(\d{1,3}([,]\d{3})*|\d{1,3})\.\d{1,})\s*Value
```

Here I get the value "12,451.5". Now I want to use If condition i.e. if the value I get is of month april(at 4th/nth postion) then do code else not

So how to get the value at nth postion?

Comment: please, post you input text in raw format

Comment: You could split the two lines by one space or more then get the index of the last value

Comment: First of all, what language are you using ?

Comment: Your explanation is difficult to understand. Please provide sample input with actual and desired output.

Comment: The snippet your posted doesn't line up properly - is this how your source data is formatted? Is there a value for every month? If so you could do something by just using an index on a matches collection but I'm until I know if there is a value for every month not much point in typing that out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

This expression will:

- find the year 2013
- capture the column header at nth position
- capture the value at nth position on the next line

Note to set the nth position you'll need to change both indicated numbers to desired value of n. The expression as shown here will capture the 3rd position.

```
^\s*2013[^\r\n]*[\r\n]+(?:\s+([a-z]+)(?=[\r\n\s]|\Z)){3}[^\r\n]*?[\r\n]+(?:[^\r\n0-9,.]+([0-9,.]+)(?=[\r\n\s]|\Z)){3}
                                                      ^                                                            ^
                                                      |                                                            |
```

[image]

This works because the by repeating the capture group n times the regex engine only remembers the last successful match. In your routine then you'd simply test the returned array to see if the second capture has a value then use that i

## Example

Live example showing the 4th position which doesn't exist in the sample text so the match fails: http://www.rubular.com/r/GUw7yLfLrQ

Live example showing the successfully found 3 position: http://www.rubular.com/r/h8Y9fKK33c

**Sample Text**

```
    2013
        Jan        Feb         March     April    May    June
       34,101.2  12,342.7    12,451.5
Value
```

**Code**

You didn't specify a language so I'm using PHP here to simply show how the expression works

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match('/^\s*2013[^\r\n]*[\r\n]+(?:\s+([a-z]+)(?=[\r\n\s]|\Z)){3}[^\r\n]*?[\r\n]+(?:[^\r\n0-9,.]+([0-9,.]+)(?=[\r\n\s]|\Z)){3}/imsx',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

**Matches**

```
[0] =>         2013
        Jan        Feb         March     April    May    June
       34,101.2  12,342.7    12,451.5
[1] => March
[2] => 12,451.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. Create a model and fill in your text to a list, then its pretty straight forward.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Regex reg = new Regex("");

            List<Model> list = new List<Model>(); //list is filled up with your items, use a streamreader if its comma delimited etc
            list.Add(new Model {Month = "Jan", Value = "2"});
            list.Add(new Model { Month = "Feb", Value = "2" });
            list.Add(new Model { Month = "Mar", Value = "3" });
            list.Add(new Model { Month = "Apr", Value = "3" });
            list.Add(new Model { Month = "May", Value = "4" });
            list.Add(new Model { Month = "Jun", Value = "2" });


            for (int i=0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                if(reg.IsMatch(list[i].Value)){
                    if (list[i].Value == list[3].Value)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(list[i].Month +" "+ "Match april");
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class Model
        {
            public string Month { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
    }
```